# PROTEGE: Using length path

Tags: sparql, owl, protege

is it possible to use [Arbitrary Length Path Matching](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#propertypath-arbitrary-length) in protege SPARQL query tab?

[image]

Comment: Works for me in Protege 5.2.0

Answer (score 5):

You are using the [Snap SPARQL Query Plugin](https://github.com/protegeproject/autoupdate/blob/master/update-info/5.0.0/plugins.repository#L76), not the [SPARQL Query plugin](https://github.com/protegeproject/autoupdate/blob/master/update-info/5.0.0/plugins.repository#L82).

Unlike the SPARQL Query plugin, the Snap SPARQL Query plugin supports querying over inferred knowledge, but does not support property paths.

From [Snap-SPARQL: A Java Framework for working
with SPARQL and OWL](http://cgi.csc.liv.ac.uk/~valli/OWLED2015/OWLED_2015_paper_21.pdf) (section 4):

> SPARQL 1.1 contains *property path expressions* that allow
>   regular-expression-like paths of properties to be matched. However,
>   these are not supported by the Snap-SPARQL  framework. While  this 
>   would  be  a  significant  limitation  under simple entailment, it is
>   not clear how much of a limitation it actually is under the OWL
>   entailment regime. This is because, one of motivations for property
>   path expressions is that they enable queries to be written whose
>   answers involve some kind of “transitivity” such as `{ ?x rdfs:subClassOf+ ?y }` or `{ ?x :partOf+ ?y }`.
>
> In these cases, under the OWL entailment regime, transitivity comes
>   “for free” according to the semantics of the language, for example if
>   `A` is a subclass of `B` and `B` is a subclass of `C`, then `A` is
>   also a subclass of `C`. For more complex cases that involve choices
>   e.g. the lack of property path expressions imposes some inconvenience
>   and queries such as `{ ?x rdfs:label | dce:title ?y }`, will need to
>   be written by the user, if possible.

Let us suppose that *i ∈ sub ⊆ sup*. Both plugins allow to "infer" that *i ∈ sup*:

- with the SPARQL Query Plugin, you need to use property paths;
- with the Snap SPARQL Query Plugin, you don't need to use property paths, and in fact you can't.

[image: Comparison]

Choose *Window > Reset selected tab to default state*, if you need the "SPARQL Query" view to be the only view on the "SPARQL Query" tab.