# Protege DL Query

Tags: sparql, ontology, protege, dlquery

I developed an Arabic ontology for chest diseases using Protege version 5.2.0 Now I'm using Description Logic query (DL query) to query the ontology but the results are different from the same query results using SPARQL query.

For example: my ontology contains classes like:

1. Disease
2. Symptom

The DL query is: `Disease and Has_Symptom value diarrhea` and the result of it is shown in the following image:

[image]

The result is all individuals of a class `Disease`, but when executing the same query using SPARQL the result is correct and is shown in the following image.

[image: SPARQL Query and its result]

Note: when using the same version of Protege with the same ontology on a different computer the DL query returns correct result. I hope this is a clear question.

I appreciate any help you provide.

Comment: Add more details. I guess, you are using the SPARQL Query plugin, not the Snap SPARQL Query plugin. The former doesn't support querying over infered knowledge, whereas the latter — as well as the DL Query plugin — does. An example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010739/7879193

Comment: Which plugin? Which query? Please provide more information...

Comment: OK, you have edited you question, but what is your "equivalent" SPARQL query? Which flags a checked on the DL Query tab (subclasses, supperclasses etc.)? Paste a minimal version of your ontology, which allows to reproduce problems. In general: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Well, try the Snap SPARQL plugin, probably this helps you. It seems that for unknown reasons a reasoner concludes that other 13 individuals belong to the class.